# Background image getting clipped in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, gsap

I've got a div with a background image set to cover. I'm setting the size of the image container to be 100px bigger than the window on all sides. Then I'm tweenlite to move the background based on the mouse pos.

Works great in FF. Not so much in Chrome/Safari. The background image looks to be clipped.

Here is a link that illustrates my issue: http://codepen.io/iknowbryan/pen/xENgrX

```
.bg{
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1100/?random) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put fixed on the background remove it.

```
background: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1100/?random) no-repeat center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Breakout the background. Sometimes background defining can be "sensative".

```
.bg{
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1100/?random);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
}
```